# In which file is the configuration of the Sound Preferences stored in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: sound, indicator-sound, audio-recording

I adjust the recording level of both the mic and the internal audio (or speakers/earphone if you like) with sliders after clicking on the audio icon and Sound Preferences in the pannel of Ubuntu Mate 16.04. These levels are conserved between successive reboots, so it is clear that they are internally stored in some file.

What file is that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Pulseaudio the sound preference files are stored in the users home directory, `~/.config/pulse/`

Volume level files are:

```
*device-volumes.tdb
*stream-volumes.tdb
```